Auto-generated manifest.h does not include ProviderGuid value
I am attempting to compile an instrumentation manifest in order to build a manifest-based Windows Event Log provider. I expect the compiled manifest.h file to include a ProviderGuid symbol, as the example here has this symbol.
My manifest.xml file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<instrumentationManifest xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events"
                         xmlns:win="http://manifests.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/windows/events"
                         xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <instrumentation>
    <events>
      <provider name="MySampleProvider"
                guid="{e585d1ba-488c-4adc-b752-f360e410d365}"
                symbol="MyProvider"
                resourceFileName="%SystemRoot%\\System32\\MySampleProvider.dll"
                messageFileName="%SystemRoot%\\System32\\MySampleProvider.dll">

        <events>
          <event symbol="EVENT_MY_EVENT" value="1"
                 version="0" level="win:Informational"
                 template="MyEventTemplate"
                 message="$(string.MyEvent.Message)"/>
        </events>

        <templates>
          <template tid="MyEventTemplate">
            <data name="Message" inType="win:UnicodeString" outType="xs:string"/>
          </template>
        </templates>

        <keywords>
          <keyword name="MyKeyword" mask="0x1"/>
        </keywords>

        <tasks>
          <task name="MyTask" eventGUID="{642836ec-9270-4b16-aacb-b971bcf357ae}" value="1"/>
        </tasks>

        <opcodes>
          <opcode name="MyOpcode" value="10"/>
        </opcodes>

        <levels>
          <level name="MyLevel" value="16" symbol="Informational"/>
        </levels>

        <channels>
          <channel name="MyChannel" chid="MySampleProvider/Operational" type="Operational" enabled="true"/>
        </channels>

      </provider>
    </events>
  </instrumentation>

  <localization>
    <resources culture="en-US">
      <stringTable>
        <string id="MyEvent.Message" value="This is a sample event message."/>
      </stringTable>
    </resources>
  </localization>
</instrumentationManifest>

I compile this file with "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\x64\mc.exe" -h . -r . manifest.xml. When I run this command, there are no errors or warnings displayed in the console.
After compiling, I searched the resulting manifest.h file, but this file does not contain ProviderGuid anywhere.
Is this expected? Am I misinterpreting what the example here is for?

I found the fix. I needed to change symbol="MyProvider" in the provider object to symbol="ProviderGuid", and then recompile. Then ProviderGuid appeared in the manifest.h file.
I realized this when I noticed the docs said

The example references the events defined in Publishing Your Event Schema for a Manifest-based Provider.

The Publishing Your Event Schema for a Manifest-based Provider page used ProviderGuid as the symbol name in the example manifest.xml.
The working manifest.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<instrumentationManifest xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events"
                         xmlns:win="http://manifests.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/windows/events"
                         xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <instrumentation>
    <events>
      <provider name="MySampleProvider"
                guid="{e585d1ba-488c-4adc-b752-f360e410d365}"
                symbol="ProviderGuid"
                resourceFileName="%SystemRoot%\\System32\\MySampleProvider.dll"
                messageFileName="%SystemRoot%\\System32\\MySampleProvider.dll">

        <events>
          <event symbol="EVENT_MY_EVENT" value="1"
                 version="0" level="win:Informational"
                 template="MyEventTemplate"
                 message="$(string.MyEvent.Message)"/>
        </events>

        <templates>
          <template tid="MyEventTemplate">
            <data name="Message" inType="win:UnicodeString" outType="xs:string"/>
          </template>
        </templates>

        <keywords>
          <keyword name="MyKeyword" mask="0x1"/>
        </keywords>

        <tasks>
          <task name="MyTask" eventGUID="{642836ec-9270-4b16-aacb-b971bcf357ae}" value="1"/>
        </tasks>

        <opcodes>
          <opcode name="MyOpcode" value="10"/>
        </opcodes>

        <levels>
          <level name="MyLevel" value="16" symbol="Informational"/>
        </levels>

        <channels>
          <channel name="MyChannel" chid="MySampleProvider/Operational" type="Operational" enabled="true"/>
        </channels>

      </provider>
    </events>
  </instrumentation>

  <localization>
    <resources culture="en-US">
      <stringTable>
        <string id="MyEvent.Message" value="This is a sample event message."/>
      </stringTable>
    </resources>
  </localization>
</instrumentationManifest>

